# Dual Channel Tuner allocation

Tags: redhawksdr

I have a dual channel tuner and am trying to allocate two channels using Frontend 2.0. I am using Redhawk 1.9 installation. When the allocateCapacity is called it says that the capacities length is 1. Should this be 2 for a dual channel tuner? I thought I read that the number of tuners is specified in the .prf.xml file, but I don't see where the number of tuners is specified. Is this the correct approach?

```
CORBA::Boolean DEVICE_i::allocateCapacity(const CF::Properties & capacities)
throw (CORBA::SystemException, CF::Device::InvalidCapacity, CF::Device::InvalidState) {
        std::cout << "In DEVICE_i::allocateCapacity...capacities length = " << capacities.length() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

A call to `allocateCapacity` should be made for each tuner. To allocate two tuners, make two calls to `allocateCapacity`.

The *capacities* in this context is referring to the request that is passed into `allocateCapacity`, not the Device capacity. A single request should be made at a time, meaning the length of the request should be 1, as you are seeing.

The capacity of the Device is advertised using the `frontend_tuner_status` struct sequence Property, which has an entry for each tuner. For a dual tuner, there should be two entries in the `frontend_tuner_status struct` sequence. This could be populated in the `.prf.xml` if known and constant, but it is more commonly populated at run-time in the Device code. To specify that there are two tuners, add two struct entries to the `frontend_tuner_status` struct sequence (either in the prf or at run-time).

The USRP_UHD is an example of a FEI 2.0 Device that supports multiple tuners that you could use as an example.